# How to print hash data as { label: "Chrome", data: 2 } in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Now my hash data is print as

```
{ :label=> "Chrome", :data=> 2}
```

but i want to print it as

```
{ label: "Chrome", data: 2}
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind quotation marks around keys use `to_json`

```
puts hash.to_json
```

If you do, nothing better comes to my mind than:

```
puts "{" + hash.map{|k,v| "#{k}: #{v.to_json}"}.join(', ') + "}"
```

Comment: Thank for your advise. to_json is ok. I just make a mistake in my word spell.